# ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 4335 exit 1> worker=0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, unicorn, ruby-1.9.3

I am trying since 2 days to deploy on my vps (Ubuntu 12.04 Server (64 bits)) using : ruby (1.9.3-rc1), rails, capistrano, nginx and unicorn.

I also follow railscast tutorial from Ryan Bates showing how to deploy on VPS from scratch.

Actualy the cap deploy:cold command seems to work fine (as all the others) but when i try to go on my url i fall on "We're sorry but something went wront" => The default error page from Rails.

In my production logs i get :

```
Migrating to CreateQuestionAnswers (20130317152603)
Migrating to CreateRegions (20130502212531)
Migrating to AddRegionIdToSection (20130502212557)
Migrating to CreateAnnonceImages (20130510130906)
Migrating to AddAttachmentImageToAnnonceImages (20130510130925)
Migrating to CreateFormations (20130510195503)
Migrating to CreateInscriptions (20130510195627)
Migrating to AddAttachmentImageToFormations (20130511182928)
Migrating to AddParamsToInscription (20130514231201)
Migrating to AddPaypalidToInscription (20130514234243)
   (0.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" 
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Creating scope :all. Overwriting existing method User.all.
Creating scope :all. Overwriting existing method User.all.
Creating scope :all. Overwriting existing method Echange.all.
Creating scope :all. Overwriting existing method Echange.all.
Creating scope :validate. Overwriting existing method Annonce.validate.
Creating scope :validate. Overwriting existing method Annonce.validate.
Creating scope :all. Overwriting existing method Article.all.
Creating scope :all. Overwriting existing method Article.all.
```

So i looked at my unicorn logs and i found this :

```
E, [2013-05-21T03:20:08.751341 #31081] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 4335 exit         1> worker=0
I, [2013-05-21T03:20:08.753997 #31081]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
E, [2013-05-21T03:20:08.790666 #31081] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 4332 exit 1> worker=1
I, [2013-05-21T03:20:08.791251 #31081]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
I, [2013-05-21T03:20:08.794600 #4341]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=4341
I, [2013-05-21T03:20:08.796302 #4341]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2013-05-21T03:20:08.802089 #4344]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawned pid=4344
I, [2013-05-21T03:20:08.803227 #4344]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2013-05-21T03:20:37.871677 #31081]  INFO -- : reloading config_file=/home/deployer/apps/avocat-immo/current/config/unicorn.rb
I, [2013-05-21T03:20:37.876045 #31081]  INFO -- : done reloading config_file=/home/deployer/apps/avocat-immo/current/config/unicorn.rb
I, [2013-05-21T03:20:38.002451 #31081]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 4344 exit 0> worker=1
I, [2013-05-21T03:20:38.002640 #31081]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
I, [2013-05-21T03:20:38.007280 #4674]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawned pid=4674
I, [2013-05-21T03:20:38.007595 #4674]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2013-05-21T03:20:38.010511 #31081]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 4341 exit 0> worker=0
I, [2013-05-21T03:20:38.010714 #31081]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2013-05-21T03:20:38.012600 #4678]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=4678
I, [2013-05-21T03:20:38.012886 #4678]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2013-05-21T03:21:08.079364 #4678]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
I, [2013-05-21T03:21:08.080779 #4674]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
I, [2013-05-21T03:21:46.897404 #31081]  INFO -- : reloading config_file=/home/deployer/apps/avocat-immo/current/config/unicorn.rb
I, [2013-05-21T03:21:46.900599 #31081]  INFO -- : done reloading config_file=/home/deployer/apps/avocat-immo/current/config/unicorn.rb
I, [2013-05-21T03:21:47.237973 #31081]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 4678 exit 0> worker=0
I, [2013-05-21T03:21:47.238160 #31081]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2013-05-21T03:21:47.241018 #31081]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 4674 exit 0> worker=1
I, [2013-05-21T03:21:47.241296 #31081]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
I, [2013-05-21T03:21:47.243055 #4919]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=4919
I, [2013-05-21T03:21:47.243287 #4919]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2013-05-21T03:21:47.245830 #4921]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawned pid=4921
I, [2013-05-21T03:21:47.246122 #4921]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2013-05-21T03:22:17.055549 #4919]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
I, [2013-05-21T03:22:17.057331 #4921]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
I, [2013-05-21T03:29:57.149534 #31081]  INFO -- : reloading config_file=/home/deployer/apps/avocat-immo/current/config/unicorn.rb
I, [2013-05-21T03:29:57.181644 #31081]  INFO -- : done reloading config_file=/home/deployer/apps/avocat-immo/current/config/unicorn.rb
I, [2013-05-21T03:29:57.997267 #31081]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 4919 exit 0> worker=0
I, [2013-05-21T03:29:57.997689 #31081]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2013-05-21T03:29:58.003458 #31081]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 4921 exit 0> worker=1
I, [2013-05-21T03:29:58.003691 #31081]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
I, [2013-05-21T03:29:58.010269 #7783]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=7783
```

Over and over ...

So here is my configs :

my unicorn.rb :

```
root = "/home/deployer/apps/avocat-immo/current"
working_directory root
pid "#{root}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"
listen "/tmp/unicorn.avocat.sock"
worker_processes 2
timeout 30
```

And here is my unicorn_init.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# Feel free to change any of the following variables for your app:
TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT-60}
APP_ROOT=/home/deployer/apps/avocat-immo/current
PID=$APP_ROOT/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT; bundle exec unicorn -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production"
AS_USER=deployer
set -u

OLD_PIN="$PID.oldbin"

sig () {
  test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

oldsig () {
  test -s $OLD_PIN && kill -$1 `cat $OLD_PIN`
}

run () {
  if [ "$(id -un)" = "$AS_USER" ]; then
    eval $1
  else
    su -c "$1" - $AS_USER
  fi
}

case "$1" in
start)
  sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
stop)
  sig QUIT && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
force-stop)
  sig TERM && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
restart|reload)
  sig HUP && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
upgrade)
  if sig USR2 && sleep 2 && sig 0 && oldsig QUIT
  then
n=$TIMEOUT
    while test -s $OLD_PIN && test $n -ge 0
    do
      printf '.' && sleep 1 && n=$(( $n - 1 ))
    done
    echo

    if test $n -lt 0 && test -s $OLD_PIN
    then
      echo >&2 "$OLD_PIN still exists after $TIMEOUT seconds"
      exit 1
    fi
    exit 0
  fi
  echo >&2 "Couldn't upgrade, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
reopen-logs)
  sig USR1
  ;;
*)
  echo >&2 "Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|upgrade|force-stop|reopen-logs>"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

I have tried

```
/etc/init.d/unicorn_avocat-immo start
/etc/init.d/unicorn_avocat-immo stop
```

I also restarted nginx but nothing seems to work. The website load in less then a sec on the error page and the website is not yet working as it should be in production.

Can anyone help me on that matter ?

**Additional informations found in nginx errors.log**

```
    2013/05/21 12:23:08 [crit] 19097#0: *16 connect() to unix:/tmp/avocat.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: **.***.**.***, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/avocat.sock:/", host: "**.***.**.***"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add   `config.log_level = :debug` in config/production.rb

you will get error log in log/production.log
paste output of that log so i can help you

also try `rake assets:precompile`

Comment: Hi, i have tried what you said. The result is in my main post that i edited. Seems the problem appear before rails even load itself ...

Comment: in config -> listen "/tmp/unicorn.avocat.sock" and in nginx  unix:/tmp/avocat.sock

Comment: also check if file exists or not , if exists then delete it and try to deploy it again.

Comment: Oh thx! so it seems that nginx tried to look for the wrong name of sock. I renamed it, it's not working yet but at least i get production log and can debug properly now. Great job faishal !

Comment: Thx. Just yesterday i deploy my first rails app for multistage. that time i also face many problems with cap, unicorn and rvm :P